# What happens when you assign a (float x1, float x2) to a float r in C?

Tags: c, numerical-methods, assign

I am reading the book Numerical Recipes in C in the chapter about the bisection algorithm for root finding but in the code I'm confounded by the following line of code:

```
rtb = f < 0.0 ? (dx=x2-x1,x1) : (dx=x1-x2,x2);
```

I know that the operator `( code1 ) ? ( code2 ) : ( code3 )`

is like a `if( code1 ) ( code2 ) else ( code3 )`

but what i don't understand is that `rtb` that is a float is receiving either `(dx=x2-x1,x1)`

or `(dx=x1-x2,x2)`, being `x1` and `x2` floats would't this be assigning some type of ordered pair of floats to a single float ?

Comment: Take a look at comma operator. rtb gets x1 or x2, not a pair.

Comment: TL;DR: It's an operator, like `+`, `/` and so on. `X, Y` is equal to `Y` (`X` is evaluated and discarded). Here it's used to make the code more terse (and slightly ugly). It essentially means `if (f < 0.0) {dx = x2-x1; rtb = x1;} else {dx = x1-x2; rtb = x2}`.